# PostgreSQL: Query for specific field in json column

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have a DB table that has a column named 'expected' which defined as json.

and one of the rows in the db has the following value:

```
expected = {"min":5, "max":20, "league_id":7}
```

I'm trying to select this row using Hibernate as follow:

```
Object[] league = (Object[])session.createSQLQuery(
                "SELECT id, name, type, expected, content " +
                "FROM bonus " +
                "WHERE CAST(expected->>league_id as numeric)=7")
                .uniqueResult();
```

I get the following exception:

```
[SqlExceptionHelper] - ERROR: column "league_id" does not exist
```

Why it tried to translate league_id into a column?

by the way, if I try this query in my pgAdmin tool it works perfectly!

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote `league_id` with `'`:

```
SELECT id, name, type, expected, content
FROM bonus
WHERE (expected->>'league_id')::int = 7;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac413/2/0)**</kbd>

> [JSON Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):
>
> ```
> ╔═════════╦══════╦═══════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════╦════════╗
> ║ Operator║ Type ║         Description           ║          Example            ║ Result ║
> ╠═════════╬══════╬═══════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════╬════════╣
> ║ ->>     ║ text ║ Get JSON object field as text ║ '{"a":1,"b":2}'::json->>'b' ║      2 ║
> ╚═════════╩══════╩═══════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════╩════════╝
> ```

Comment: @Shvalb It should. Didn't you even try it? I have not environment set up for testing it. But it is clearly problem with query.

Comment: I tried it and I had to change a bit the syntax to:    CAST(expected->>'league_id' as numeric)    because ::int would confuse hibernate.

Comment: but using this code I got another exception:     org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Comment: @Shvalb What kind of do exception you get?

Comment: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Comment: @Shvalb `SELECT id` and check for each column. You probably have bad mapping.

Comment: I changed the query to do :  select * ...  but same exception.

Comment: @Shvalb `SELECT name` and so on. `*` changes nothing. Don't be lazy. Check which column causes problem.

Comment: You're probably right about the JSON. It worked when I mapped single column!! so now I will deal with the JSONs.